# how call method in jsp, help me

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@Repository
public class MenuDAOImpl implements MenuDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Menu> showMenus(String typemenu) {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Menu.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("Id", 1));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Status", 1));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Menutype", typemenu));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("Lft"));
        return criteria.list();
    }

}


public interface MenuService {

    public List<Menu> showMenus(String typemenu); 

}


@Service
public class MenuServiceImpl implements MenuService {

    @Autowired
    private MenuDAO menuDAO;

    @Transactional
    public List<Menu> showMenus(String typemenu) {
        return menuDAO.showMenus(typemenu);
    }
}



<% List<Menu> listmenu = DefaultMenuBar.buildMenuBar("adminmenu");%>
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.dnict.spring3mvc.main.service.MenuServiceImpl.showMenus(MenuServiceImpl.java:90)
>     com.dnict.utilities.DefaultMenuBar.buildMenuBar(DefaultMenuBar.java:13)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.admin_002dtiles.menu_jsp._jspService(menu_jsp.java:67)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:927)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
>     org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
>     org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
>     org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
>     org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
>     org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
>     org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
>     org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
>     org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
>     org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
>     org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
>     org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.admin_002dtiles.baseLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(baseLayout_jsp.java:252)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.admin_002dtiles.baseLayout_jsp._jspService(baseLayout_jsp.java:174)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
>     org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
>     org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
>     org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
>     org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
>     org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
>     org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
>     org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
>     org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)

Comment: What is your question? Help you do what?

Comment: Call method showMenus() in jsp

Comment: Already posted by the user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601427/spring-call-method-in-jsp

Comment: sessionFactory null :((

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
MySpringService srvObject = (MySpringService) wac.getBean("mySpringService");//mySpringService mean bean id of MySpringService 
List<myspringservice> lst= srvObject.listAll();
```

Reference link:

http://codexamples.blogspot.in/2010/05/how-to-access-spring-service-from.html

http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/11/01/accessing-spring-session-beans-in-jsp/